# How to stop one scheduler iteration in Python

Tags: python, scheduler

I am new to the Python (and programming in general). I have a pcode that periodically downloads the website content through PyCURL and do some searching. I have used scheduler inside the While-True to set up an infinite loop where I create an object and call its method start()to grab the website and perform some searchs.. Problem occurs when getbody() methon can't fetch the website, due to the connection problems (or another reasons). BeautifulSoup expects the string, raises an Error otherwise.

How to stop a Thread of the scheduler programme when an Error/Exception occurs right in the getbody() method and so wait for another Thread? Returning an empty string as a result of getbody() method is a waste of cpu time.

```
#Parser_module
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = BeautifulSoup(self.getbody(), "lxml")
        self.buffer = BytesIO()

    def getbody(self):
        # some code to set pycurl up
        try:
            c.perform()
        except pycurl.error:
            print("connection error")
            # returns an emptry string to feed the BeautifulSoup with
            return ""
        body = self.buffer.getvalue().decode("utf-8")
        return body

     def start(self):
         #calls other functions to perform some searching
         self.otherfunction()

     def otherfunction(self):
         .
         .
         .

#Scheduler module
import Parser_module
from threading import Timer

def start_search():
    parser = Parser()
    parser.start()
    t = Timer(20.0, start_search)
    t.start()
```

Comment: I cannot follow where your while-True takes place could you give a bit more detail ? if the things raising the error are called within the loop you could try and except that specfic error and call ```continue``` within the except clause which will skip an interation and ignore what ever was next.

Comment: @Francisco Vargas - I was calling start_search() function from the While loop, but as I think about it, it has no use there because timer provides infinite code processing itself. But didn't know about the `continue`. Very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fetching the URL in the `Parser.__init__`, you could just do that in `Parser.start` and return if an error occurs.

```
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = None
        self.buffer = BytesIO()

    def start():
        data = self.getbody()
        if not data:
            return
        self.body = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
        self.otherfunction()

    def getbody(self):
        ...

    def otherfunction(self):
        ...
```

On a side note, I suggest that you use the much nicer [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library instead of pycurl, if you can. Also check out [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python Style Guide, e.g. for some suggestions on how to name things.

Comment: I like the idea of fetching the URL in `start()` function, it makes lot of things easier. And will definitely look at requests library. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer ;)